# GIMP: How to make path tool snap to whole pixels?

Tags: gimp, path

By default GIMP path tool uses one decimal point when setting nodes. Is it possible to make nodes snap to whole pixels (For example, make a node at 64.3 snap to 64.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Paths tool doesn't set nodes. It puts nodes where you ask it to. If you want the anchors on integer pixels, then use guides or the grid (and `View>Snap to guides|grid`). Btw, even though the position display only shows one decimal digit you can get a better accuracy (about 1/256th of a pixel).

Comment: Thank you, it works. Although `Snap to grid` only works if the grid is enabled.

Comment: The grid does not have to be visible in order to snap to it, if this is what you mean by "enabled".